# Deserialize JSON in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, json-deserialization

Is there a way to properly deserialize an json in swift that is this structure?

```
{
Usuario =     (
            {
        "picture_url" = "";
        id = 229;
        name = "ABC";
    }
);}
```

I tested this with jsonHelper library

```
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers )
let jsonString = jsonData
var mstemp = [usuario]()
mstemp <-- jsonString
```

but only worked for jsons this structure

```
{"name": "myUser", "id": "1","picture_url": ""}
```

**Update**

code:

```
let urlFinal = URLSERVIDOR+"/ws/rest/Geral/consultaUsuario?token=\(validotoken)&email=\(validoEmail)&senha=\(SenhaCriptada)"
let jsonUrl = urlFinal
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl!) {data, response, error in
    guard data != nil else {
        falha()
        return
    }

    do {
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers )
        let jsonString = jsonData
        var mstemp = [usuario]()
        mstemp <-- jsonString
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            sucesso(usuarioBaixado: mstemp)
        });
    } catch _ {
        falha()
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `jsonData` will be a dictionary containing the parsed JSON data.

Comment: I need to read the json data, for example ... print(user.name) @rmaddy

Comment: OK, what's stopping you from doing that? Do you know how to access values from a Swift dictionary? `jsonData` is just a plain old Swift dictionary. You access its data like any other dictionary.

Comment: my data is in the structure of the first json, but my code returns nil for everything that is not in the second json structure @rmaddy

Comment: You haven't posted any code that attempts to get data from `jsonData`.

Comment: And still you have not posted any code that actually tries to get values from the `jsonData` dictionary. Your use of `jsonString`, `mstemp`, and `usuario` make no sense.

Comment: Use Jsonjoy library that you can "print(user.name)" from your data model class. I use it plus Alamo fire to json request. Both work side by side perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: shotsUrl!) {
    (data, response, error) in

    guard data != nil else {
        return
    }

    guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject],
        let usuario = json["Usuario"] as! AnyObject else {
            return
    }
    print ("Usuario:\n\t\(usuario["id"] as! Int)")
    print ("\t\(usuario["name"] as! String)")
    print ("\t\(usuario["picture_url"] as! String)")
}
```